# web3 angular not working in IE 11

Tags: web3js, nodejs, angular2

Have a problem with web3.
In the project on angular use this library. In all browsers everything is good but in ie 11 it gives an error and does not load.

[image]

Error in this line

```
const {keccak256, keccak256s} = __webpack_require__("../../../../web3/packages/web3-eth-accounts/node_modules/eth-lib/src/hash.js");
```

Can't find identifier, and crashed all app! 
Error throws in IE only. 
All polyfills install to angular, if I excluded this lib, project run correctly.
Thanks for any idea.

Comment: Use web3 version 1.0.0_beta18, node v 6.11.2, npm 3.10.10

Comment: This bug was fixed in web3 version 1.0.0_beta21. Big thanks.(Or maybe app start work in IE 11 because I install  crypto-js library).
If after update library doesn't work, just try run in terminal 

**`npm install crypto-js -D`**